# API to get Screen Time Stats in Android

Tags: android, usage-statistics

tl;dr : I want to get the screen on time for today, yesterday, or any past date.

I can't seem to find how I can get stats related to the screen on time of the device in my app on Android. I have come across the [UsageStats API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats) but that returns the usage stats for different apps.

I know that it can be done for any android device (maybe from a specific version of android) because there is an App called [ActionDash](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actiondash.playstore&hl=en_IN) which has this feature. Can someone please tell me how?

Comment: Did you find any way

Comment: @YogeshPaliyal I didn't complete that project but I think an idea would be to use https://pub.dev/packages/app_usage and up all the stats maybe.

Comment: i want for native android

Comment: @YogeshPaliyal you can refer to this https://medium.com/@quiro91/show-app-usage-with-usagestatsmanager-d47294537dab

Comment: i already checked all medium and StackOverflow but nothing full fill my need